# Какой алгоритм нужен для нахождении минимальной суммы из массива, которая больше Х?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Столкнулся с проблемой на олимпиаде, так как не знаю много алгоритмов, на этой задаче попал в тупик.
Значит, есть массив из положительных чисел, и есть число (Допустим, число - 28, а массив - 11, 5, 68, 9, 10, 13). Нужно найти минимальную сумму, которая больше, чем число 28 (в данном случае - 29 из 11, 13, 5). Индексация слагаемых, их колличество не важны, выводится только сумма.
Как называется алгоритм для таких задач, где можно о нём почитать, и как его реализовать?

Comment: Можете указать ограничения на значения чисел и длину массива? Так будет легче понять подходят ли Вам предложенные решения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, модифицировать subset sum с помощью динамического программирования.

Сделать массив длиной сумма+минимальное число из исходного массива, в нулевой элемент записать единицу

Потом заполнить табблицу -  для каждого исходного элемента v поставить единицы для тех сумм (ячеек), которые можно составить с использованием этого элемента

```
 if (a[i-v])
    a[i] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы начал с перебора. Перебор на небольшом наборе отработает хорошо

```
void Main()
{
    int[] numbers = new[] {11, 5, 68, 9, 10, 13};   
    int minSum = 28;
    Array.Sort(numbers);        
    int curSum = numbers.Sum();

    if(curSum < minSum) {
        Console.WriteLine("Нет решений");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(findMinSum(numbers, 0, minSum));  
}

int findMinSum(int[] numbers, int index, int minsSum, int curSum = 0)
{           
    if (curSum > minsSum) return curSum;    
    if (index >= numbers.Length) return int.MaxValue;       
    return Math.Min(findMinSum(numbers, index+1, minsSum, curSum + numbers[index]),
    findMinSum(numbers, index+1, minsSum, curSum));
}
```